# Rails 5.0 to 5.1 - 'Cant cast Hash' on one-to-many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, ruby-on-rails-5

I am migrating my app from rails 5.0 to 5.1 and am getting the error 'Cant cast Hash' when accessing an associated model (everything works fine at 5.0).

sighting.rb:

```
belongs_to :species, :class_name => 'Species', :foreign_key => 'species_id'
belongs_to :site, :class_name => 'Site', :foreign_key => 'site_id'
belongs_to :creator, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'creator_id'
belongs_to :spotter, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'spotter_id'
```

species.rb:

```
has_many :sightings, :class_name => 'Sighting', :foreign_key => 'species_id', :dependent => :restrict_with_exception
```

site.rb:

```
has_many :sightings, :class_name => 'Sighting', :foreign_key => 'site_id', :dependent => :restrict_with_exception
```

At the console (having seeded the database):

```
Sighting.find(1).site
```

returns the correct site model.

```
Sighting.find(1).species
```

on the other hand returns the error

```
TypeError: can't cast Hash
```

Both associated models (as well as the User model - not shown) are all set up in the same manner. And as I say if I revert back to rails 5.0 everything works fine again.

Answer (score 0):

This very much looks like the issue described in https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/29299

Fixed has been merged into `5-1-stable` branch
https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/29058

You can wait for `v5.1.4`
or you can load that branch, in your Gemfile

`gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails', branch: '5-1-stable'`